# static mocking is already registered in the current thread

Tags: java, mockito, mockstatic

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
  private AutoCloseable autoCloseable;

  @BeforeEach
  void init() throws InterruptedException {
    autoCloseable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
  }

  @AfterEach
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    autoCloseeable.close();
  }
```

In one of the tests I'm using Mockito.mockConstruction to mock the behavior of an object created inside the method being tested. When I run the testsuite, the test fails with

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  For
> com.stocktrader.service.ib.ltp.GetStockOrFuturesPrice, static mocking
> is already registered in the current thread
>
> To create a new mock, the existing static mock registration must be
> deregistered

If I run the test individually, it succeeds. Any idea why?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you are seeing occurs when the static mocking is already registered in the current thread for the class . To create a new mock, the existing static mock registration must be deregistered.

It’s possible that the test runs successfully when run individually
because the static mock registration is not present in the current
thread. When you run the entire test suite, the static mock
registration may be present in another thread, causing the error
message you are seeing.

Deregistering the existing static mock registration before creating a new mock should solve this issue.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
  private AutoCloseable autoCloseable;

  @BeforeEach
  void init() throws InterruptedException {
    autoCloseable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
  }

  @AfterEach
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    autoCloseeable.close();
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    try (MockedStatic<GetStockOrFuturesPrice> mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(GetStockOrFuturesPrice.class)) {
      mocked.when(() -> GetStockOrFuturesPrice.getPrice(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(10.0);
      // Your test code here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question already includes "must be deregistered". _How_ does one deregister? Where does your answer show how this deregistration works?

Comment: As you can see, the problematic example code is not complete, only because of the error, you can see the code that must be solved.

The solution is just as Nischal Sharma puts it.
Follow his instructions and you will solve it.
Using try with resources is the solution. If you have more questions, you can review this link https://rieckpil.de/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito-java-kotlin/. I see no need to rewrite what is already written. Greetings.